# How to use only Method of inbuilt portlet in our custome portlet?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I just want to know that is that any facility liferay provides in which we just use the function of the inbuilt portlet?

E.g i have some custom portlet and i want to just add some document to the database table of document and media portlet from my custom portlet .so is it possible?

i don't want to use its GUI just i need to access its function or say action.

if i can call this way the adduser method of any inbuilt portlet in my own portlet 
com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser

So can i use that way?and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i have understood the question, but you can of course use many provided services anywhere in your portlet.
For example if you want to save a file you have uploaded from the page, you can use something like:

```java
protected FileEntry saveFile(String name, File file, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay) throws PortalException, SystemException{
    _log.debug("request of saving new file " + name);
    if (file == null){
        _log.debug("file content is null.. save aborted");
        return null;
    }
    if (!StringUtils.hasLength(name)){
        _log.debug("file name is null.. save aborted");
        return null;
    }
    long defaultRepoId = DLFolderConstants.getDataRepositoryId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
        ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
        serviceContext.setSignedIn(true);
        serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
        serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
        Folder folder = fetchFolder(defaultRepoId);
        long folderId = (folder != null ? folder.getFolderId() : DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
        FileEntry entry = DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(defaultRepoId, folderId, name, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), name, "", "", file, serviceContext);
        _log.debug("file " + name + " saved successfully");
        return entry;
    }
```

Is this what you are looking for?
In a similar way you can add many types of entity (users, wiki nodes, documents, ...)

Note that `DLAppServiceUtil`is provided by Liferay (6.1, maybe different in 6.0 due to changes on document library)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.i think u understood my question and to access this method i just need to import the respective portlet in my page or action class..right?

Comment: u just need to import the DLAppServiceUtil class into your page like any other java import. The class must be in your classpath if you are using the eclipse plugin and u created a liferay project (if not, you can add liferay facets by right-click on project -> Liferay menu)